# Selenium - Java data driven Framework suggestion

Tags: java, selenium, framework

[Dropdown Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Moscd.png)

I have 3 dropdowns with multiple components in the UI.
Have incorporated data driven java selenium framework, data is fetched from excel sheet:

[Excel sheet- where data is fetched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7grYG.png)

This data I am taking in to main class:

```
public class TC01_newDesign extends TestBase{

    login obj_login;
    createNewDesign obj_CreateNewDesign;
    saveDesign obj_SaveDesign;
    capacitorUnit obj_capacitorUnit;
    logout obj_logout;




    @Test (priority=1, description = "Login Functionality") 
    public void login() {

        log.info("Open CapDes URL.");
        driver.get(data.getProperty("base.url"));
        obj_login = new login (driver);
        ExcelBase.setExcelFileSheet("Capacitor_unit");
        obj_login.enter_username(ExcelBase.getCellData(3,1));
        obj_login.enter_password(ExcelBase.getCellData(3,2));
        obj_login.select_login();
    }

    @Test (priority=2, description = "Create new Design")   
    public void createNewDesign() {

        log.info("Create New Design");
        obj_CreateNewDesign = new createNewDesign (driver);
        obj_CreateNewDesign.select_newButton();
        obj_CreateNewDesign.select_productDropDown();
        obj_CreateNewDesign.wait_dropdown();
        obj_CreateNewDesign.choose_productDropDown(ExcelBase.getCellData(3,4));
        obj_CreateNewDesign.select_powerQCDropDown();
        obj_CreateNewDesign.wait_dropdown();
        obj_CreateNewDesign.choose_powerQCDropDown(ExcelBase.getCellData(3,5));
        obj_CreateNewDesign.select_FeederFactoryDropDown();
        obj_CreateNewDesign.wait_dropdown();
        obj_CreateNewDesign.choose_FeederFactoryDropDown(ExcelBase.getCellData(3,6));
        obj_CreateNewDesign.select_okButton();
        obj_CreateNewDesign.wait_ok();
    }
```

Then control goes to Page class - **Here I want your valuable suggestion to improve the code**

```
public class createNewDesign extends PageBase {

    public createNewDesign(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
    WebDriver driver;
    // Web Element for New button in left panel 
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='v-panel-content v-scrollable']//div[2]//div[1]//div[1]//div[1]//span[1]//img[1]")
    WebElement newButton;

    // Web Element for Product drop down button
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='v-filterselect v-widget v-filterselect-required v-required v-filterselect-prompt']//div[@class='v-filterselect-button']")
    WebElement productDropDown;

    /*******************************************************************************************/
    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - Capacitor Unit
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Capacitor Unit\")]")
    WebElement productChoose1;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - Capacitor Unit SC
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Capacitor Unit SC\")]")
    WebElement productChoose2;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - Capacitor DC Unit
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Capacitor DC Unit\")]")
    WebElement productChoose3;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - Surge Cap
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Surge Cap\")]")
    WebElement productChoose4;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - QBank-A
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"QBank-A\")]")
    WebElement productChoose5;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - QBank-A SC
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"QBank-A SC\")]")
    WebElement productChoose6;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - QBank-AS
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"QBank-AS\")]")
    WebElement productChoose7;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - QBank-BS
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"QBank-BS\")]")
    WebElement productChoose8;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - QBank-CS
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"QBank-CS\")]")
    WebElement productChoose9;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - QBank-B
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"QBank-B\")]")
    WebElement productChoose10;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - QBank-C
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"QBank-C\")]")
    WebElement productChoose11;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - Q-Pole
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Q-Pole\")]")
    WebElement productChoose12;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - QBank-PLC
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"QBank-PLC\")]")
    WebElement productChoose13;

    // Web Element for chosen product(s) - QBank-H
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"QBank-H\")]")
    WebElement productChoose14;

    /*******************************************************************************************/

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center drop down
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='v-filterselect v-widget v-filterselect-required v-required v-filterselect-prompt']//div[@class='v-filterselect-button']")
    WebElement powerQCDropDown;

    /*******************************************************************************************/

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose1;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - 10th Of Ramadan, Egypt
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"10th Of Ramadan, Egypt\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose2;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose3;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose4;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose5;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose6;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose7;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose8;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose9;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose10;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose11;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose12;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose13;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose14;

    // Web Element for Power Quality Center Option - Ludvika, Sweden
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Ludvika, Sweden\")]")
    WebElement powerQCChoose15;

    /*******************************************************************************************/

    // Web Element for Feeder factory drop down
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='v-filterselect v-widget v-filterselect-required v-required v-filterselect-prompt']//div[@class='v-filterselect-button']")
    WebElement FeederFactoryDropDown;

    // Web Element for Feeder factory Option - TBA
    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Xi'an, China\")]")
    WebElement FeederFactoryChoose;

    // Web Element for OK (Submit) button
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='v-button v-widget primary v-button-primary']")
    WebElement okButton;

    // Web Element for waiting for drop down element
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='v-filterselect-suggestmenu']")
    WebElement waitdropdown;

    // Web Element for waiting for OK
    @FindBy(xpath = "//td[@class='v-formlayout-captioncell']//span[contains(text(),'Unit voltage (V)')]")
    WebElement waitok;


    /*******************************************************************************************
     * All Methods for performing actions
     * @return 
     *******************************************************************************************/



    public void select_newButton(){
        log.info("Select New design button");
        newButton.click();

    }


    public void select_productDropDown(){
        productDropDown.click();

    }

    public void choose_productDropDown(String data){
        log.info("Product Selected: " + data);
        if(data.contains("Capacitor Unit"))
        {
            productChoose1.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("Capacitor Unit SC"))
        {
            productChoose2.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("Capacitor DC Unit"))
        {
            productChoose3.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("Surge Cap"))
        {
            productChoose4.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("QBank-A"))
        {
            productChoose5.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("QBank-A SC"))
        {
            productChoose6.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("QBank-AS"))
        {
            productChoose7.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("QBank-BS"))
        {
            productChoose8.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("QBank-CS"))
        {
            productChoose9.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("QBank-B"))
        {
            productChoose10.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("QBank-C"))
        {
            productChoose11.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("Q-Pole"))
        {
            productChoose12.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("QBank-PLC"))
        {
            productChoose13.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("QBank-H"))
        {
            productChoose14.click();
        }
        else
            log.error("Enter valid Product name");
    }

    public void select_powerQCDropDown(){
        powerQCDropDown.click();

    }

    public void choose_powerQCDropDown(String data){
        log.info("Power Quality Centre selected: "+ data);
        if(data.contains("Ludvika, Sweden"))
        {
            powerQCChoose1.click();
        }
        if(data.contains("10th Of Ramadan, Egypt"))
        {
            powerQCChoose2.click();
        }



    }
    public void select_FeederFactoryDropDown(){
        FeederFactoryDropDown.click();
    }

    public void choose_FeederFactoryDropDown(String data){
        log.info("Feeder Factory selected: "+data);
        FeederFactoryChoose.click();

    }
    public void select_okButton(){
        log.info("Select Ok button");
        okButton.click();
    }

    public void wait_dropdown(){
        TestBase.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(waitdropdown));

    }
    public void wait_ok(){
        TestBase.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(waitok));

    }

}
```

As I am again taking the same name in both xpaths of the drop down and in If loop for different drop down.

Basically what I want is the value from Excel once taken as input, has to be handled efficiently in the code.

Disclaimer: I am new to Java-Selenium, hence asking for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your element selectors should be unique. For example, both of these elements contain text 'Capacitor Unit'. Maybe choose an ID or class to select them by. Or match the exact text:

Your comments here is also wrong. It's not selected multiple products (`List<WebElement>`) it's selecting 1 each:

```
// Web Element for chosen product(s) - Capacitor Unit
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Capacitor Unit\")]")
WebElement productChoose1;

// Web Element for chosen product(s) - Capacitor Unit SC
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),\"Capacitor Unit SC\")]")
WebElement productChoose2;
```

`TC01_newDesign` is a bad name. It only has meaning to you.

You seem to have your own naming styles for variables, classnames, methodnames. As a Java developer I am only use to seeing the standard lower camel case for variables, upper camel case for Classes and uppercase with underscores for static variables. It's very surprising to see any other style used for Java. I strongly suggest adapting standard naming conventions.

I'd be interested in seeing the actual tests. Methods such as `choose_productDropDown` make it difficult to actually test anything. Why bother logging an error in a test? Fail the test with a message instead (You may want to do it in the actual test, outside of this method, but since you don't return anything how could you?)